# Parsing JSON string with dynamic element name and convert it to xml

Tags: c#, xml, json

I have the following JSON

```
{
 "points": {
   "darts": {
     "top": {
       "10": 7.6,
       "9": 1.8,
       "4": 11
     },
     "first": {
       "10": 34
     }
   },
   "other": [
     {
       "double": {
         "156.47": [
           "10-9"
         ]
       }
     },
     {
       "triple": {
         "5027.64": [
           "10-9-4"
         ]
       }
     },
     {
       "second": {
         "4.50": [
           "9"
         ]
       }
     }
   ],
   "numOther": 3
 }
}
```

and I'd like to get the following result:

```
<points>
    <darts>
        <top>
            <point num="4" points="11" />
            <point num="9" points="1.8" />
            <point num="10" points="7.6" />
        </top>
        <first>
            <point num="10" points="34" />
        </first>
    </darts>
    <other>
        <double>
            <point num="10-9" points="156.47" />
        </double>
    </other>
    <other>
        <triple>
            <point num="10-9-4" points="5027.64" />
        </triple>
    </other>
    <other>
        <second>
            <point num="19" points="4.50" />
        </second>
    </other>
    <numOther>3</numOther>
</points>
```

The main issue that I can't parse it straight to xml because of the numeric elements.

But, I've manage to get the children elements but not the data by using this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8856084

Any ideas?