# How do I parse a JSON object in C# when I don't know key and properties don't have names?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Here is my unparsed JSON:

> { "1": [ [ [ 2015, 6, 1, 8, 0, 0, 3600, "Europe/London", "BST", 1 ], [
>   2015, 6, 1, 9, 30, 0, 3600, "Europe/London", "BST", 1 ] ], [ [ 2015,
>   6, 1, 8, 30, 0, 3600, "Europe/London", "BST", 1 ], [ 2015, 6, 1, 10,
>   0, 0, 3600, "Europe/London", "BST", 1 ] ], [ [ 2015, 6, 1, 9, 0, 0,
>   3600, "Europe/London", "BST", 1 ], [ 2015, 6, 1, 10, 30, 0, 3600,
>   "Europe/London", "BST", 1 ] ], [ [ 2015, 6, 1, 9, 30, 0, 3600,
>   "Europe/London", "BST", 1 ], [ 2015, 6, 1, 11, 0, 0, 3600,
>   "Europe/London", "BST", 1 ] ] ], "2": [ [ [ 2015, 6, 2, 8, 0, 0, 3600,
>   "Europe/London", "BST", 1 ], [ 2015, 6, 2, 9, 30, 0, 3600,
>   "Europe/London", "BST", 1 ] ], [ [ 2015, 6, 2, 8, 30, 0, 3600,
>   "Europe/London", "BST", 1 ], [ 2015, 6, 2, 10, 0, 0, 3600,
>   "Europe/London", "BST", 1 ] ], [ [ 2015, 6, 2, 9, 0, 0, 3600,
>   "Europe/London", "BST", 1 ], [ 2015, 6, 2, 10, 30, 0, 3600,
>   "Europe/London", "BST", 1 ] ], [ [ 2015, 6, 2, 9, 30, 0, 3600,
>   "Europe/London", "BST", 1 ], [ 2015, 6, 2, 11, 0, 0, 3600,
>   "Europe/London", "BST", 1 ] ] ], "3": [ [ [ 2015, 6, 3, 8, 0, 0, 3600,
>   "Europe/London", "BST", 1 ], [ 2015, 6, 3, 9, 30, 0, 3600,
>   "Europe/London", "BST", 1 ] ], [ [ 2015, 6, 3, 8, 30, 0, 3600,
>   "Europe/London", "BST", 1 ], [ 2015, 6, 3, 10, 0, 0, 3600,
>   "Europe/London", "BST", 1 ] ], [ [ 2015, 6, 3, 9, 0, 0, 3600,
>   "Europe/London", "BST", 1 ], [ 2015, 6, 3, 10, 30, 0, 3600,
>   "Europe/London", "BST", 1 ] ], [ [ 2015, 6, 3, 9, 30, 0, 3600,
>   "Europe/London", "BST", 1 ], [ 2015, 6, 3, 11, 0, 0, 3600,
>   "Europe/London", "BST", 1 ] ] ], "4": [ [ [ 2015, 6, 4, 8, 0, 0, 3600,
>   "Europe/London", "BST", 1 ], [ 2015, 6, 4, 9, 30, 0, 3600,
>   "Europe/London", "BST", 1 ] ], [ [ 2015, 6, 4, 8, 30, 0, 3600,
>   "Europe/London", "BST", 1 ], [ 2015, 6, 4, 10, 0, 0, 3600,
>   "Europe/London", "BST", 1 ] ], [ [ 2015, 6, 4, 9, 0, 0, 3600,
>   "Europe/London", "BST", 1 ], [ 2015, 6, 4, 10, 30, 0, 3600,
>   "Europe/London", "BST", 1 ] ], [ [ 2015, 6, 4, 9, 30, 0, 3600,
>   "Europe/London", "BST", 1 ], [ 2015, 6, 4, 11, 0, 0, 3600,
>   "Europe/London", "BST", 1 ] ] ]}

This is the basic format:

ROOT

```
 Day of the month

      time slot

           time slot start

           time slot end
```

This is what it looks like formatted:

[image: JSON Viewer]

I cannot figure out for the life of me how to drill through this. This question should be similar to [How do I parse a JSON object in C# when I don't know the key in advance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855494/how-do-i-parse-a-json-object-in-c-sharp-when-i-dont-know-the-key-in-advance)

If I do the following, I get "System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue."

```
        JObject objTimes = JObject.Parse(strJson);

        foreach (var day in objTimes["1"])
        {
            divTimes.InnerHtml += day[0][0][0];
        }
```

Comment: Blinding us with the full content of the JSON isn't helpful. You can cut it down to 5 lines and still represent the nature of the JSON at hand.

Comment: If this question is similar to the other, did that other one help? If not why? Chances are you'd receive similar answers. Please read [ask]

Comment: Try posting your JSON to http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and you will be able to see the structure more easily.  The root object is some sort of dictionary with the keys being integer-valued string and the values being nested arrays.  Load it with `JObject.Parse`.

Comment: Looks like the innermost array represents the fields of some class: `[ 2015, 6, 3, 9, 30, 0, 3600, "Europe/London", "BST", 1 ]`  Can you design a class that represents this data?  I can't guess what each of these fields mean.

Comment: I cut the JSON down. The other question and answer did not help because the formatting of my JSON is strange but I do not have control of the JSON. I think the other question didn't help because my JSON isn't the "name : value" format.

Comment: @dbc [ year, month, day, hour, min, seconds, 3600, "Europe/London", "BST", GMT offset ]

Comment: Create intermediate vars to track down where the error is coming from, are you sure you are getting 1 correctly?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to design a class (named, e.g., `Entry`) to represent the data representing the lowest level of array in the JSON: `[ 2015, 6, 3, 9, 30, 0, 3600, "Europe/London", "BST", 1 ]`.  Then create a [`JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) to load the array values sequentially into the array.  Finally deserialize the outer dictionary and arrays as appropriate:

Here is one possible class to represent the data of a single inner array:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(EntryConverter))]
public class Entry
{
    public Entry()
    {
        // You need to determine whether the time numbers in the JSON are in UTC or in the timezone given in the "TimeZone" field.  If
        // Local, change to DateTimeKind.Local
        DateTime = new DateTime(0, DateTimeKind.Utc); 
    }

    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; } // That 3600 thing.  No idea what it's for.
    public string Destination { get; set; }
    public string TimeZone { get; set; }
    // Not all time zone offsets are integers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9204:30
    public decimal GmtOffset { get; set; }
}
```

Next, the converter:

```
public class EntryConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(Entry).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    void SetField(Entry entry, int index, JValue value)
    {
        switch (index)
        {
            case 0:
                entry.DateTime = new DateTime((int)value, entry.DateTime.Month, entry.DateTime.Day, entry.DateTime.Hour, entry.DateTime.Minute, entry.DateTime.Second, entry.DateTime.Millisecond, entry.DateTime.Kind);
                break;
            case 1:
                entry.DateTime = new DateTime(entry.DateTime.Year, (int)value, entry.DateTime.Day, entry.DateTime.Hour, entry.DateTime.Minute, entry.DateTime.Second, entry.DateTime.Millisecond, entry.DateTime.Kind);
                break;
            case 2:
                entry.DateTime = new DateTime(entry.DateTime.Year, entry.DateTime.Month, (int)value, entry.DateTime.Hour, entry.DateTime.Minute, entry.DateTime.Second, entry.DateTime.Millisecond, entry.DateTime.Kind);
                break;
            case 3:
                entry.DateTime = new DateTime(entry.DateTime.Year, entry.DateTime.Month, entry.DateTime.Day, (int)value, entry.DateTime.Minute, entry.DateTime.Second, entry.DateTime.Millisecond, entry.DateTime.Kind);
                break;
            case 4:
                entry.DateTime = new DateTime(entry.DateTime.Year, entry.DateTime.Month, entry.DateTime.Day, entry.DateTime.Hour, (int)value, entry.DateTime.Second, entry.DateTime.Millisecond, entry.DateTime.Kind);
                break;
            case 5:
                entry.DateTime = new DateTime(entry.DateTime.Year, entry.DateTime.Month, entry.DateTime.Day, entry.DateTime.Hour, entry.DateTime.Minute, (int)value, entry.DateTime.Millisecond, entry.DateTime.Kind);
                break;
            case 6:
                entry.Number = (int)value;
                break;
            case 7:
                entry.Destination = (string)value;
                break;
            case 8:
                entry.TimeZone = (string)value;
                break; 
            case 9:
                entry.GmtOffset = (decimal)value;
                break;
            default:
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException(index.ToString());
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var array = JArray.Load(reader);
        if (array == null)
            return existingValue;
        var entry = (existingValue as Entry ?? new Entry());
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
        {
            SetField(entry, i, (JValue)array[i]);
        }
        return entry;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And then use it like:

```
        var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, List<List<Entry>>>>(json);
        Debug.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, Formatting.Indented));
```

Here I compressed all the time information into a single `DateTime` for conciseness, though you might not want to do this.  Also, it's unclear whether the time information is in UTC or in local time.  If local then my use of `DateTime.Kind` is wrong.

You could extend the converter to serialize the fields in the same order if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's somewhat loose implementation with JSON.NET.

First the definition classes. TimeSlotInfo holds info about DayOfMonth and timeslots available for that Day of month:

```
public class TimeSlotInfo
{
    public int DayOfMonth { get; set; }

    public List<TimeSlotRange> TimeSlots { get; set; }

    public TimeSlotInfo()
    {
        TimeSlots = new List<TimeSlotRange>();
    }
}

public class TimeSlotRange
{
    public TimeSlotItem Start { get; set; }

    public TimeSlotItem End { get; set; }
}

public class TimeSlotItem
{
    public int Year { get; set; }

    public int Month { get; set; }

    public int Day { get; set; }

    public int Hour { get; set; }

    public int Minute { get; set; }

    public int Second { get; set; }

    public int SecondsInHour { get; set; }

    public string TimezoneStr { get; set; }

    public string BST { get; set; }

    public int SomeNum { get; set; }

    public DateTime AsDateTime
    {
        get { return new DateTime(Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second); }
    }

    public static TimeSlotItem CreateFromJTokenList(List<JToken> tokenList)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = new TimeSlotItem
            {
                Year = tokenList[0].Value<int>(),
                Month = tokenList[1].Value<int>(),
                Day = tokenList[2].Value<int>(),
                Hour = tokenList[3].Value<int>(),
                Minute = tokenList[4].Value<int>(),
                Second = tokenList[5].Value<int>(),
                SecondsInHour = tokenList[6].Value<int>(),
                TimezoneStr = tokenList[7].Value<string>(),
                BST = tokenList[8].Value<string>(),
                SomeNum = tokenList[9].Value<int>()
            };

            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And then you need a parser to fill those objects:

```
var timeSlotInfoList = new List<TimeSlotInfo>();

var jsonVal = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\test.json"); // Somehow get JSON string into jsonVal. Not neccessarily from file.
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonVal) as JObject;
if (obj != null)
{
    var jobj = obj.AsQueryable();
    foreach (JProperty item in jobj)
    {
        try
        {
            var dayOfMonth = Convert.ToInt32(item.Name);

            var timeSlotInfo = new TimeSlotInfo
            {
                DayOfMonth = dayOfMonth
            };
            timeSlotInfoList.Add(timeSlotInfo);

            var timeSlots = item.Value.ToList();
            foreach (var timeSlotPair in timeSlots)
            {
                var timeSlotPairList = timeSlotPair.ToList();
                if (timeSlotPairList.Count != 2)
                    continue;

                var slotItemStart = TimeSlotItem.CreateFromJTokenList(timeSlotPairList[0].ToList());
                var slotItemEnd = TimeSlotItem.CreateFromJTokenList(timeSlotPairList[0].ToList());

                if (slotItemStart != null && slotItemEnd != null)
                {
                    timeSlotInfo.TimeSlots.Add(new TimeSlotRange
                    {
                        Start = slotItemStart,
                        End = slotItemEnd,
                    });
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

At the end `timeSlotInfoList` contains list of all Days of months and its TimeSlots (with ranges from Start to End).

This code might need some more tweaking regarding exceptions, validation, etc, but this is some basic idea about parsing such a thing.
If I've made any mistake I'd appreciate some comment about it. Anyway, hope it helps.