# How to get Key:Value pair from JSON JArray?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm working on a project where i want to extract some data from this link (http://www.eurogamer.net/ajax.php?action=json-comments&aid=1822104&start=0&limit=1000&filter=all&order=asc)

One part of this json file is here: `[{"id":6044586,"u":"ubergine","uid":"472505","a":"2011\/community\/users\/4\/7\/2\/5\/0\/5\/user-472505-originalxoriginal-16-30-27.jpg","t":"3 weeks ago","k":"+16",**"p":"Prepare to Tri"**,"e":"","d":"","v":"unverified","gi":[],"s":"","mod":false,"total":"28"}]`

I've tried `Regex` but didn't find any good. Then I used `Json.NET` using `JArray` it parses the data and used `JToken` but could not get. I'm using C# programming Language. 
I want the specific value of `p` key bold above?

Comment: The JSON is invalid. [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com)

Comment: What programming language are you using ?

Comment: @Utkanos the json on link provided by the OP is valid.

Comment: I'm using c# language.

Comment: how is it invalid?

Comment: Json is valid at jsonlint.com

Comment: may be this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855494/how-do-i-parse-a-json-object-in-c-sharp-when-i-dont-know-the-key-in-advance) will help you..

Comment: JSONLint tells me it's invalid... AH, because for some reason the OP has `**` in it.

Comment: Exactly what data are you trying to extract?  You wrote *I used `Json.NET` using `JArray` it parses the data and used `JToken` but could not get.*  Can you share what you tried and where you got stuck?

Comment: Actually I've tried a lot of snippets but couldn't get the answer. Like...
WebClient c = new WebClient();
string json = c.DownloadString(siteLinkGivenAbove);
var arr = JArray.Parse(@json);
JToken token = arr.SelectToken("id"); // tried to access inner key but it throws an exception of instance is not set.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer on another forum. It may help others.
Here is the piece of code:

```
    JArray parsedArray = JArray.Parse(jsonString);
        foreach (JObject parsedObject in parsedArray.Children<JObject>())
        {
            foreach (JProperty parsedProperty in parsedObject.Properties())
            {
                string propertyName = parsedProperty.Name;
                if (propertyName.Equals("p"))
                {
                    string propertyValue = (string)parsedProperty.Value;
                    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Value: {1}", propertyName, propertyValue);
                }
            }
        }
```

And Here is the link for Complete code answer: 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/df1d6c1b-349a-4f7f-9168-5bf01d320075/how-to-get-keyvalue-pair-from-json-jarray?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score 1):

You may be better of making a class that maps to the json properties and using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<>()`.

See this linqpad script:
http://share.linqpad.net/7fpltw.linq

source here (note this is a LinqPad script so you will get errors if you just paste into visual studio):

```
void Main()
{
string thejson = @"[{
    ""id"": 6044586,
    ""u"": ""ubergine"",
    ""uid"": ""472505"",
    ""a"": ""2011\/community\/users\/4\/7\/2\/5\/0\/5\/user-472505-originalxoriginal-16-30-27.jpg"",
    ""t"": ""4 weeks ago"",
    ""k"": ""+16"",
    ""p"": ""Prepare to Tri"",
    ""e"": """",
    ""d"": """",
    ""v"": ""unverified"",
    ""gi"": [],
    ""s"": """",
    ""mod"": false,
    ""total"": ""28""
}, {
    ""id"": 6044596,
    ""u"": ""Fragtaster"",
    ""uid"": ""828120"",
    ""a"": ""2014\/community\/users\/8\/2\/8\/1\/2\/0\/user-828120-originalxoriginal-8-03-00.jpg"",
    ""t"": ""4 weeks ago"",
    ""k"": ""+44"",
    ""p"": ""This [Dark Souls 3] is one of those cases where <strong>\""more of the same\""<\/strong> is a bloody damn good-thing.<br \/>\n<br \/>\n<img src=\""https:\/\/tse2.mm.bing.net\/th?id=OIP.M607bf0698ed2368b9f9cc9e4ea244c77H0&pid=15.1\"" \/>"",
    ""e"": """",
    ""d"": """",
    ""v"": ""unverified"",
    ""gi"": [],
    ""s"": """",
    ""mod"": false,
    ""total"": ""66""
}]";

    var theobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonData>>(thejson);
    theobj.ForEach(o => o.p.Dump());
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class JsonData
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string u { get; set; }
    public string uid { get; set; }
    public string a { get; set; }
    public string t { get; set; }
    public string k { get; set; }
    public string p { get; set; }
    public string e { get; set; }
    public string d { get; set; }
    public string v { get; set; }
    public string[] gi { get; set; }
    public string s { get; set; }
    public string mod { get; set; }
    public string total { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is this Dump() method? it is not built-in.

Comment: It is a [LinqPad thing](https://www.linqpad.net/). You could use `Console.WriteLine()` instead.