# selecting the first 2 FIELDS in a JSON OBJECT

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have some JSON that looks like this:

```
{
  "innerObj1": {
    "1. Information": "unimportant"
  },
  "innerObj2": {
    "2017-09-19 16:00:00": {
      "number1": "75.4500"
    },
    "2017-09-19 15:55:00": {
      "number2": "75.4200"
    }
  }
}
```

Not sure why `innerObj2` is not returned as an array (this is from an api) but I have to get `number1` and `number2` returned as an array of strings.  Note that `2017-09-19 16:00:00` and `2017-09-19 15:55:00` are subject to change, so I can't hardcode the selection of those objects in C#. I was thinking of possibly using LINQ, but I'm not sure how. I've really only used them with JSON arrays.

Comment: Please include any relevant code samples, and mention/tag what API you're using.

Comment: You can use something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855494/how-do-i-parse-a-json-object-in-c-sharp-when-i-dont-know-the-key-in-advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Json.Net, you can get the values of the innermost properties into an array like this, without needing to know the names of them:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);

string[] numbers = ((JObject)obj["innerObj2"]).Properties()
    .SelectMany(jp => ((JObject)jp.Value).Properties())
    .Select(jp => (string)jp.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5sLy6M

Or, a simpler alternative which does the same thing using [`SelectTokens`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) with a [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) wildcard expression:

```
string[] numbers = obj.SelectTokens("innerObj2.*.*")
                      .Select(jt => (string)jt)
                      .ToArray();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CyRQ9T